# How to make a dynamic area echarts in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to make the area chart dynamically, where the chart is live
where the temperature will update based on `tempGenerator()`

**chart.component.ts**

```
export interface templogRecord {
  dateandtime: string,
  sensor: string,
  temperature: string,
  humidity: string
    }

export class RoomListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  rowData: templogRecord[] = [];

    trendChart() {
        let historyRefuelling = [["2018-08-15T10:04:01.339Z",50],
        ["2018-08-15T10:08:01.339Z",50],
        ["2018-08-15T12:01:13.914Z",7],["2018-08-15T13:14:13.914Z",3]]



        this.rowData = record.default.records;
        this.trendOption = [];

        this.trendOption = {
          title: {
            text: 'Humidity',
            x: '50%',
            y: '3%'
          },
          tooltip: {
            showContent: true,
          },
          legend: {
            show: false,
            y: '10%',
            data: [ 'Humidity']
          },
          calculable: false,
          xAxis: [
            {
              type: 'category',
              boundaryGap: false,
              axisLabel: {
                formatter: function(data: Date){
                  return format(new Date(data), 'MMMM DD, YYYY [\n] HH:MM a')
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          yAxis: [
            {
              type: 'value',
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              axisLabel : {
                  formatter: '{value} °C'
              }
            }
          ],
          series: [
            {
              name: 'Humidity',
              type: 'line',
              smooth: true,
              color: '#ff7b7b',
              itemStyle: { normal: { areaStyle: { type: 'default' } } },
              data: historyRefuelling
            }
          ]
        }

        console.log(this.rowData, ' -=--=--')
        console.log(this.trendOption)
        console.log(
          new Date(+(new Date()) + Math.floor(Math.random()*10000000000))
          )
      }

 tempGenerator() {
        var time = 12;
        var num = Math.random() * 100;
        var tempBase = Math.round(num);

        var fluc = [0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.5, 1, 1, 1, 1,
          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

        return tempBase * fluc[time];
      }
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Heat 1",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Dash Seal Area",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Cloud Seal Area",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Nine Seal Area",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Sam",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Samp",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        },
        {
            "dateandtime": "2018-06-14 02:24:02",
            "sensor": "Sensing",
            "temperature": "25.9",
            "humidity": "99.9"
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using echarts direcly or the ngx-echarts package?

Comment: @LucaRegazzi I'm using ngx-echarts package

Comment: ok then, you have to supply a new input property to your chart called `merge` with the updated series. the chart will then automatically update everytime you update the series. I'll post an example as an answer

Comment: @LucaRegazzi okay thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment, to update the chart you need to provide the `merge` input to your chart in the html. the merge input have to be binded to a variable that you update with the new chart options.

I modified a bit your example to make it easier for me to update the data but you get the idea.

In the example you will notice 2 things:

- I added the new `[merge]` property in the html file binded to the `mergeOptions` variable
- I used a setInterval (but you can take the more Angular way using Observable.timer) to update the `mergeOtions` with the data from your `tempGenerator` function.

[EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8spncc)

Comment: how'bout when there's a new update the old days should remove

Comment: how do I shift the previous date?

Comment: Use the shift function on the array to remove the first value before pushing the new one

Comment: but the index doesn't remove

Comment: how to remove the index ?

Comment: What do you mean? Shift automatically remove the first element of the array

Comment: If you need more help, please open a new question or update this one

Comment: Can you use the merge option for any type of echart? I am trying to use it for sunburst, and it does not seem to be working. For line and bar it is perfect.

Comment: It should work, `[merge]` is general option provided by ngx-echarts to update chart in realtime